# How to customize the output of my BLASTP output form

Tags: bioinformatics, database, blast

I'm trying to align the output of I got previously to against the swissprot database, and I need to have an output in tabular form with `-qseqid -sacc -qlen -slen -length -nident -pident -evalue -stitle` and I want to set the `evalue less than 1e-10`. Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
blastp -query Trinity.fasta.transdecoder.pep \
    -db swissprot \
    -outfmt "6 qseqid sacc qlen slen length nident pident evalue stitle" -evalue 1e-10 1>Predict.txt \
    2>wrongPredicted.err
```

However this is the first several lines of output I got in the txt file :

```
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1::g.132::m.132   Q964E0  400     376     376     364     96.81   0.0     RecName: Full=Actin, cytoplasmic; Contains: RecName: Full=Actin, cytoplasmic, intermediate form; Flags: Precursor
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1::g.132::m.132   Q964D9  400     376     376     364     96.81   0.0     RecName: Full=Actin, cytoplasmic; Contains: RecName: Full=Actin, cytoplasmic, intermediate form; Flags: Precursor
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1::g.132::m.132   P53472  400     376     376     364     96.81   0.0     RecName: Full=Actin, cytoskeletal 1A; AltName: Full=Actin, cytoskeletal IA; Flags: Precursor
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1::g.132::m.132   P92179  400     376     376     364     96.81   0.0     RecName: Full=Actin, cytoplasmic; Contains: RecName: Full=Actin, cytoplasmic, intermediate form; Flags: Precursor
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1::g.132::m.132   Q964E1  400     376     376     363     96.54   0.0     RecName: Full=Actin, cytoplasmic; Contains: RecName: Full=Actin, cytoplasmic, intermediate form; Flags: Precursor
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1::g.132::m.132   Q964E2  400     376     376     364     96.81   0.0     RecName: Full=Actin, cytoplasmic; Contains: RecName: Full=Actin, cytoplasmic, intermediate form; Flags: Precursor
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1::g.132::m.132   P69004  400     376     376     364     96.81   0.0     RecName: Full=Actin-15B; Flags: Precursor
TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1::TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1_i1::g.132::m.132   O17320  400     376     376     361     96.01   0.0     RecName: Full=Actin
```

The problem is that all the evalue is 0.0 for some reasons, cuz what I want is something like this :

```
TRINITY_DN8_c0_g1_i1 Q5ZKK7 283 788 64 53 82.81 1e-30 RecName: Full=General transcription and DNA repair factor IIH helicase subunit XPB; Short=TFIIH subunit XPB; AltName: Full=DNA excision repair protein ERCC-3
TRINITY_DN8_c0_g1_i1 Q7ZVV1 283 782 64 53 82.81 3e-30 RecName: Full=General transcription and DNA repair factor IIH helicase subunit XPB; Short=TFIIH subunit XPB; AltName: Full=DNA excision repair protein ERCC-3
TRINITY_DN8_c0_g1_i1 Q1RMT1 283 782 64 52 81.25 6e-30 RecName: Full=General transcription and DNA repair factor IIH helicase subunit XPB; Short=TFIIH subunit XPB; AltName: Full=DNA excision repair protein ERCC-3
TRINITY_DN8_c0_g1_i1 Q5RA62 283 782 64 52 81.25 7e-30 RecName: Full=General transcription and DNA repair factor IIH helicase subunit XPB; Short=TFIIH subunit XPB; AltName: Full=DNA excision repair protein ERCC-3
TRINITY_DN8_c0_g1_i1 Q60HG1 283 782 64 52 81.25 7e-30 RecName: Full=General transcription and DNA repair factor IIH helicase subunit XPB; Short=TFIIH subunit XPB; AltName: Full=DNA excision repair protein ERCC-3
```

The 8th column should be valid evalue. Need some help! Thank you!

Comment: Very low e values are rounded to zero, so that’s a valid output.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question seems like it might be a better fit for [Bioinformatics.SE], but please do **not** [crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/), instead request migration after consulting that sites help and checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

- 0 is a valid e-value. It is the strongest e-value you can get.
- the sequence identifier in a FASTA file (and thus what BLAST uses) is "everything up to the first space". If what you have behind "::" is indeed useless, you should remove it from your query before submitting it.

---

FWIW, [my lab](https://wurmlab.com) makes SequenceServer, a powerful graphical interface for running BLAST. It enables you to [run BLAST in the cloud](https://sequenceserver.com/cloud) or on your local computer.

Comment: Good answer, but three links to your own application? Really!

Comment: Hi @David - Sorry I didn't mean to cause offence. I'm quite proud of what our app has accomplished: SequenceServer helps me and 1000s of others perform and interpret BLAST analyses every week. Anyhow, I've removed 1 of the 2 links to the app.